# Parsing the SLA from Jira API

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, itil

I am currently in the process of using the Jira API to pull some data on tickets created into a separate database.

Tickets have been designed to follow ITIL standards and have a 'Time to first response' and a 'Time to resolution'

Both of these are retrieved in Jason as the following:

```
<customfield_10110>com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.sla.model.SLAValue@619c2aec</customfield_10110>
<customfield_10111>com.atlassian.servicedesk.internal.sla.model.SLAValue@705770b9</customfield_10111>
```

It looks like there is a Hex value, but how do I get that to show the actual TTR and TTFR value I see in the ticket?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was a bug that was fixed in version 2.0